# Move a downloaded File. IO Exception File used by another Process

Tags: c#, asp.net, file

I downloaded a file like this.

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
   client.Proxy = new WebProxy();
   client.DownloadFile(@tb.Text, "new.png");
}
```

then i want to move it.

```
File.Move("new.png", path);
```

After i tried this, i tried...

```
using (var fileStream = new StreamReader("new.png"))
{
   File.Move("new.png", path);         
}
```

but both version are throwing the File uses by another Process exception.
How can i avoid this?

Comment: Where is the code between `DownloadFile` and `File.Move`? The only way you'd get an exception with a `File.Move` after downloading would be because the file is still opened, perhaps by some other stream? Is there code you forgot to post? The second attempt is *exactly* that - how do you expect to move a file that you've already opened for reading? Please post the *exact* code you used and the *full* exception as returned by `Exception.ToString()`

Comment: I am not doing anything with the File. I just want to download it and the move/rename.

Comment: What @Panagiotis is asking, is where in your code you call `File.Move()`. Show a [mcve]. Anyway you can search the web for "C# File uses by another Process" and find plenty of hints that will help you troubleshoot this issue. There are tools that can show which process holds a lock on a file. It might be a virus scanner, for example.

Comment: If you're not doing anything with the file, then why the StreamReader code? Anyway, that last code piece _can't_ work; the StreamReader will obviously block the file, causing the Move command inside the brackets to fail.

Comment: so the streamreader version is something i found after i searched the web... and i dont know how to show a specific version of my code because i dont do anything thats related to this file... I

Answer (score 1):

You could just download the file straight into the wanted path, like this:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
   client.Proxy = new WebProxy();
   client.DownloadFile(@tb.Text, Path.Combine(path, "new.png");
}
```

Here are some info on [Path.Combine(..)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine(v=vs.110).aspx) if you want it :)

Answer (score -1):

```
using (var fileStream = new StreamReader("new.png"))
{
   File.Move("new.png", path);         
}
```

Why not just call File.Move("new.png", path) outside the using

```
using (var fileStream = new StreamReader("new.png"))
{
   // To your stuff
}
File.Move("new.png", path);
```

Comment: OP already tried that.

Comment: @Pikoh the OP probably did something else as well, because calling `File.Move` after downloading shouldn't result in an exception

Comment: while, it works for me. Please share your what is the value of your "path"

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos well, he said he tried first `File.Move("new.png", path);` and then using the StreamReader. If he lied, i can't do anything about it ;)

Comment: @Pikoh you should try to *verify* first, especially if the observed behaviour doesn't make sense